# Fallout shelter catastrophic failure in about 2 hours

Tags: fallout-shelter

(Shelter 169/188 population, 2, 3 depending out in the wild, all rooms properly filled and powered )

For some reason, all my dwellers lost "happiness" from a global of 80% to 10% in about 2 hours.

All my resources tumbled to near zero ( all in the red zone)
All my dwellers are sick and irradiated.

The only thing that I can see as the cause of that is that there was a raider invasion that resulted in 2 dead (and revived).

I am not certain of the game mechanics when there is a failure like that.

Any hints ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happened to me when I left the game mid-raider attack. I wasn't able to log back in for a few hours and when I did, the same thing happened (loss of people/resources/happiness).

I have not read any 'official' comments regarding this, but leaving the game during any event causes the dwellers not to respond properly.

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible that you ran out of power? When the power goes out, other rooms (such as the cafeteria and the water treatment plant) risk going offline, and when they power down, they don't produce resources, regardless of how many people are in them.

Radiation in the vault comes from lack of Water, and Sickness (low HP) comes from lack of Food. Thankfully, dwellers don't seem to die from lack of water or food. Unhappiness (which results in loss of productivity) can come from a variety of things, and one of those things is working next to dead dwellers. If those dwellers were in the Power room, it's possible that power output was not at capacity, and with a growing vault, that can easily lead to catastrophe.

**As far as hints to recover the vault:**
If you have caps to spare, make sure all of your power rooms are triple-wide. Build a power room right next to another power room (no elevators in between) and they will join, up to three rooms wide. Really, all of your production rooms should be triple-wide, if you can afford it. After they are all triple-wide, you can work on upgrading them.

**After you're out of caps:**
Click the bottlecap icon in the upper left. This will bring up your vault roster. Click the title of the SPECIAL column to sort your dwellers by Strength. Click the dweller with the highest strength, and assign them to the power room. Continue in this fashion until the power room is filled, and do the same for any other power rooms. Change the SPECIAL column to Agility or Perception and fill your food and water rooms with whoever isn't in a power room. Don't worry about any other rooms you might have at this point.

**Next:**
Collect any finished resources, and immediately close the game. Double-tap your device's home button, and swipe the app upward. This will ensure that no disasters occur while you wait for resources to be generated. Assuming the highest-level people are in each room, this should only take 2-3 minutes at most, but you don't want to take any chances when your people are at such low health. Every minute you spend in game is another minute raiders or roaches could wipe your vault.

**If an incident does happen:**
Immediately move your dwellers out of the target room(s). Once the incident has passed out of any room, move as many dwellers as will fit INTO that room, because the incident will not return to that room. After the incident passes, everyone will return to the room they were in before the incident happened, so don't worry about trying to reassign them afterward, just continue where you left off.

Good luck! It might seem difficult at first, but I'd once rebuilt a massive vault where all but three people died, so you can do it! Just remember: don't remove dead vault dwellers who are wearing items if you can help it, because you'll lose those items! Revive those dwellers if you can!

Comment: Bonus Tip: If two rooms of the same type don't join up, it's either because one's been upgraded to a higher level, or they're already triple wide. Once you upgrade the lower-level one to the same level, they will merge and create a higher-output room. But try to build wide rooms first before upgrading them. It's more efficient that way.

Comment: Most of my production rooms are 3 wide and fully upgraded and have properly assigned dwellers. I will check your last tip when there is an incident happening.
(see accepted answer for a potential explanation)

Comment: If the appropriate room is full of properly armed, healthy dwellers, incidents should not be a problem. These tactics only need to be used when your dwellers are low on health or otherwise incapacitated. Successfully defeating an incident WILL raise morale, whereas failing an incident will probably lower it (and raiders will steal your resources).

Answer (score 2):

You might have forgotten to close the app (if you're in IOS you need to close it, not just exit, as it still runs in the background). This was our first mistake before so every time we came back after 2 hours everything was in the red - basically because it runs in the background and you aren't collecting the resources actively but they keep using it up.

Answer (score 1):

This is why you need a Mr. Handy
Ok, first of all try tp wait till the end of a raider attack(about 5 mins) or a disaster
Also try to have Mr. Handys at the power generator as power is the most important item
Try to close the app (not just exit for iOS)
Have Mr. Handys at ALL floors producing food and water. Why? Because I believe Mr. Handys run for the same time as [Background running]